# Set display name from nickname with register process

Tags: functions, user-registration

It is possible set display name from entered string into nickname registration field? I trying do this with simple hook, but after all it is not work.

```
function set_default_display_name( $user_id ) {
  $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
  $name = $user->nickname;
  $args = array(
    'ID' => $user_id,
    'display_name' => $name
  );
  wp_update_user( $args );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'set_default_display_name' );
```

By default, immediately after registration, display name was set from WP username (login) not nickname. Can sombody help me to set a display name from nickname?

Comment: username and nickname are the same upon registration,I guess?

Comment: By default registration yes. But i have registration form whereby each user can set own nickname beside username. So when somebody set nickname different than username the problem is that the display name was taken from username, not nickname. I need to set display name from nickname.

Comment: Check out this Stack Overflow answer, it may be relevant to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326315/wordpress-change-default-display-name-publicy-as-for-all-existing-users

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the hook,instead just use wp_update_user when the form is filled out and you are ready to create the user:

```
wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id,  'display_name' => $posted['nickname']) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wordpress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/):

> This action hook allows you to access data for a new user immediately
> after they are added to the database. The user id is passed to hook as
> an argument.
>
> **Not all user meta data has been stored in the database when this
> action is triggered**. For example, nickname is in the database but
> first_name and last_name are not (as of v3.9.1). The password has
> already been encrypted when this action is triggered.

You could use `update_user_meta` function in order to update any user meta field.
Since the `display_name` hasn't been updated yet, you can collect the user data (just like you did) that has been collected and decide which information you want to include in the `display_name` value. You can then use this:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'display_name', $name );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?